Excel, compare only day and month
The problem that I have, is that I want to compare 2 dates, a date that I have in cell and today's date, but I only want to compare day and month, not year and I don’t know how to do it, please someone can help me
I tried using the and function, but it doesn’t work all the time

Use day and month functions

Welcome to the board.  Could you edit your question and add some sample data.  When you say compare do you mean if they're equal?  =AND(DAY(A1)=DAY(TODAY()),MONTH(A1)=MONTH(TODAY()))?
